# How to assign Pandas.Series.str.extractall() result back to original dataset? (TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index)

Tags: pandas, extract, assignment-operator

**Dataset brief overview**

```
dete_resignations['cease_date'].head()
```

gives

[image: result]

```
dete_resignations['cease_date'].value_counts()
```

gives

[image: result] of the code above

---

**What I tried**

I was trying to extract only the year value (e.g. 05/2012 -> 2012) from 'dete_resignations['cease_date']' using 'Pandas.Series.str.extractall()' and assign the result back to the original dataframe. However, since not all the rows contain that specific string values(e.g. 05/2012), an error occurred.

Here are the code I wrote.

```
pattern = r"(?P<month>[0-1][0-9])/?(?P<year>[0-2][0-9]{3})"
years = dete_resignations['cease_date'].str.extractall(pattern)
dete_resignations['cease_date_'] = years['year']
```

'TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index'

---

I thought the 'years' share the same index with 'dete_resignations['cease']'. Therefore, even though two dataset's index is not identical, I expected python automatically matches and assigns the values to the right rows. But it didn't

Can anyone help solve this issue?

Much appreciated if someone can enlighten me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the years, then don't catch the month in `pattern`, and you can use `extract` instead of `extractall`:

```
# the $ indicates end of string
# \d is equivalent to [0-9]
# pattern extracts the last digit groups
pattern = '(?P<year>\d+)$'
years = dete_resignations['cease_date'].str.extract(pattern)
dete_resignations['cease_date_'] = years['year']
```

Comment: Thank you so much Quang!

Comment: One more question, how can \d+ extract only year value? (e.g. 05/2012 -> 2012)  Should't the pattern be assigned as '(?P<year>\d+{4})$'?

Comment: `\d+` means grab all digits, `\d{4}` means grab 4 digits. You can use either. Also if it helps, consider upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much! Upvoted but unfortunately, since my reputation is less than minimum it is not shown.